# Sveltekit update reactive variable from form action

Tags: javascript, forms, svelte, sveltekit, supabase

**Hi!**

So I'm working on a simple crud application with Sveltekit and Supabase. I'm trying to implement this sorting feature by fetching the table with the added .order() function when the user selects a sorting option. My problem is that I want to update the smoothies variable after the form action takes place with the new sorting option. Right now I'm just returning smoothies like I would in the load function but that doesn't seem to be right. So, how would I go about updating smoothies, and the dom, with the new data from the form action (and not reload the page as it would just get overriden by the default load function).

I am a Sveltekit and Supabase newbie so your help is greatly appreciated!

**+page.svelte**

```
<script>
    import { enhance } from '$app/forms';

    export let data;

    $: ({ smoothies } = data);

    const tabs = (e) => {
        e.target.classList.add('tab-active');

        const siblings = e.target.parentNode.children;

        for (let i = 0; i < siblings.length; i++) {
            if (siblings[i] !== e.target) {
                siblings[i].classList.remove('tab-active');
            }
        }
    };

    const handleSubmit = ({ form, data, action, cancel, submitter }) => {
        return async ({ result, update }) => {};
    };
</script>

<div class="flex flex-col items-center mx-auto gap-8">
    <a role="button" href="/create" class="btn btn-success mt-8">Create Smoothie</a>

    <form action="?/sortSmoothies" method="POST" use:enhance={handleSubmit}>
        <div class="tabs tabs-boxed">
            <button
                type="submit"
                name="created_at"
                value="true"
                class="tab tab-active"
                on:click={(e) => tabs(e)}>Created</button
            >
            <button type="submit" name="title" value="true" class="tab" on:click={(e) => tabs(e)}
                >Title</button
            >
            <button type="submit" name="rating" value="true" class="tab" on:click={(e) => tabs(e)}
                >Rating</button
            >
        </div>
    </form>

    <div class="grid 2xl:grid-cols-4 xl:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-2 gap-6 mt-4">
        {#each smoothies as smoothie}
            <div class="card w-96 bg-base-100 shadow-xl">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-title">{smoothie.title}</h2>
                    <p>{smoothie.method}</p>
                    <div class="rating absolute -right-5 -top-5">
                        <div
                            class="mask mask-star-2 bg-orange-400 w-12 h-12 flex items-center justify-center font-bold"
                        >
                            {smoothie.rating}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-actions justify-end">
                        <a role="button" href="/{smoothie.id}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Edit</a>
                        <form action="?/deleteSmoothie" method="POST">
                            <input type="hidden" name="smoothie" value={JSON.stringify(smoothie)} />
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-error btn-sm">Remove</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {/each}
    </div>
</div>
```

**+page.server.js**

```
import { supabase } from '$lib/supabaseClient';
import { fail } from '@sveltejs/kit';

const fetchSmoothies = async (orderBy) => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('smoothies')
        .select()
        .order(orderBy, { ascending: false });

    if (error) {
        throw new Error('Could not fetch smoothies');
    }

    return data ?? [];
};

export const load = async () => {
    console.log('load');
    const data = await fetchSmoothies('created_at');

    return {
        smoothies: data ?? []
    };
};

export const actions = {
    deleteSmoothie: async ({ request }) => {
        let { smoothie } = Object.fromEntries(await request.formData());
        smoothie = JSON.parse(smoothie);

        try {
            await supabase.from('smoothies').delete().eq('id', smoothie.id);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return fail(500, { message: 'Could not delete smoothie' });
        }
    },
    sortSmoothies: async ({ request }) => {
        console.log('action');
        const formData = Object.fromEntries(await request.formData());

        let orderBy;
        for (const prop in formData) {
            if (formData[prop] === 'true') {
                orderBy = prop;
                break;
            }
        }

        const data = await fetchSmoothies(orderBy);
        console.log(data);

        return {
            smoothies: data ?? []
        };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generally not return page data from form actions. When using the `enhance` action, a successful action will automatically invalidate the page data causing `load` to run again which in turn should update your list.

Though in this case, you might want to turn the sorting variable into a query parameter, that way the `load` function can access it and return the list in the correct order. You also would not need an action but instead use `goto` to update the URL with the new parameter.

Simplified example:

```js
function sort(e) {
    const url = new URL($page.url);
    url.searchParams.set('sort', e.currentTarget.value);
    goto(url.href, { replaceState: true });
}
```

```html
<select on:change={sort}>
    <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
    <option value="desc">Descending</option>
</select>
```

```js
// +page.server.js
export const load = e => {
    const sort = e.url.searchParams.get('sort');
    // ...
};
```

Of course you can use multiple parameters, use a form's `submit` event to trigger the sorting, etc.